# reading battery level ble Xcode

Tags: iphone, core-bluetooth, batterylevel

I have written an app which I am trying to get and update the battery level on my cB-OLP425 module.

I have used the following code but sometimes it gives me a value of 70 and at other times it gives me a value of -104.  I have looked at numerous posts and tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
if([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180F"]]) {
        for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
            NSLog(@"discovered service %@", service.UUID);
            if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A19"]]) {
                NSLog(@"Found Notify Characteristic %@", characteristic.UUID);
                 self.mycharacteristic = characteristic;
                [self.testPeripheral readValueForCharacteristic:mycharacteristic];
                [self.testPeripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:mycharacteristic];

               char batlevel;
                [mycharacteristic.value getBytes:& batlevel length:0];

                int n = (float)batlevel;
                int value = n ;

                self.batteryLevel = value;
                NSLog(@"batterylevel1;%f",batteryLevel);
            /* [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setFloat: batteryLevel forKey:@"battery_level"];*/
                           }
             } }
 }
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
{
if([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"2A19"]]) {
                NSLog(@"Found Battery Characteristic %@", characteristic.UUID);
 [mycharacteristic.value getBytes:& batteryLevel length:0];

                return;
 }
 [self.delegate peripheralDidReadChracteristic:mycharacteristic withPeripheral:testPeripheral withError:error];
}
```

Could someone please help me!!

Comment: Are you sure that getBytes: with length=0 is going to read anything from the NSData? You probably see some random value, nothing more.

Comment: I have entered a length of 1 and got the same value.  What should I use

Comment: Have you tried using `bytes` instead of `getBytes: length:`?

Also, the value should be longer than that.  A 32 bit float is 4 bytes.  A length of zero bytes doesn't make any sense.

And do you even know what data type you are supposed to be getting out of that?  Maybe it is an unsigned int or something?

Comment: I have tried values 1 - 4 with no better results.  I have also tried bytes but got 0 for a value.  I am not sure what data type I am trying to get. but I have seen this code in several different posts.

Comment: Have you tried any of the general tool apps? Blexplr, Lighblue or any other? Does your peripheral expose the value correctly? If you confirm this, then the issue is in your code, for sure.

Comment: Yes I have used ConnectBlues cB-OLP425 app from the app store and it gives me a reading for the battery that is correct.  I went into the ble module and looked at the stack firmware and it says  **Typedef** struct  uint8 BatteryLevel;  so should I change my code to deal with this?

Comment: I had another look at the original code I was looking at and found I had rearranged this so when I put them back correctly they worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getBytes` seems to be the issue. We read the battery level in our app using:

```
UInt8 batteryLevel = ((UInt8*)value.bytes)[0];
```

You could also do it with:

```
UInt8 batteryLevel;
[value getBytes:&battery length:1];
```

You need to make sure the type is `UInt8` otherwise you would read it into the wrong location.

Also, don't read the value right away in the `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService`. Wait until you get notified that the value has been updated. The docs state:

> When you attempt to read the value of a characteristic, the peripheral calls the peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error: method of its delegate object to retrieve the value. If the value is successfully retrieved, you can access it through the characteristic’s value property, like this: